# help with intuation regarding littles law - if arival rate > service rate, shouldnt the queue explode?

Tags: queueing-theory

Little law states that the average arrival rate(AR) multiple the average rate of service time(SR) equals the number of customers in the system.

But intuitively, if AR > SR shouldn't the system exploded with customers? because on avg, we 'can't keep up' with the number of customers that arrive?

In a deterministic system ar>sr indeed it's stated that the system will explode. but not when it's on average :/
Can't wrap my head around that "contradiction"

Comment: what is your SR exactly ?? Little Law states that the average number of customers is the product of average arrival rate (which dimension is inverse of a duration) and average time spent by customers in queue (which dimension is a duration). So either your definition of SR is wrong, either there is no sense to compare AR and SR.

Comment: @Optidad SR*AR=#customers in the system - what I wrote it what is stated in Wikipedia.

Comment: Okay but I just point your definition of SR. For me, "average rate of service time" does not make sense. A rate is definitely not a time. SR should be the average time customers spend in the queue. This is not, as you believe, the queue processing rate.